# Defining SQL 2008 store within GeoServer 2.3

Tags: geoserver, sql

I want to define a SQL server 2008 store within Geoserver 2.3.
I installed the sql Extension.

After defining the different attributes, I get the following error message :

```
Error creating data store, check the parameters. Error message: Unable to obtain connection: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.".)
```

The data I entered :
host -localhost/sqlr2 
port - 1433
database - the database name within SQL
scheme - dbo
user & password = A geoserver user i defined within sql

Thanks in advance
Lauren

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Make sure that your TCP/IP on SQL Server is active. Look on the SQL Server Configuration Manager in Protocol for  TCP/IP must be'active'
2. Click double to TCP/IP you get TCP/IP properties. In the folder IP-Adresses go to IPAll and you can see the port number.
3. Use netstat to check is SQL on port listen.

Now, it shuold be possible to connect the SQL Server to Geoserver. If not, try your local IP indeed of 'localhost'.

Comment: i did all of that and i still have the same problem and i'm notice in system information that No strong cryptography available, installation of the unrestricted policy jar files is recommended i'm using geoserver 2.5 that comes with boundless